# jquery ajax response data not showing in page source code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response, cart

I am working on a shopping cart from where if user click on plus icon then the item is added to cart and if user want to add same item again in cart then user will click that item plus icon and item will be updated in cart on that same row.

The following is items html:

```
<div class="Menudetail">
    <h1>Title <span>Add </span> <label>Price</label></h1>
            <div class="Menudetailtitle">soup menu</div>

    <div class="Menudproducts">
                <div class="itemscontainer">
        <div id="itemname_10" class="itemname">soup item 1</div>
        <div id="itemprice_10" class="itemprice">1200</div>
        <div class="itemaddsign">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="sessid" id="sessid" value=""  />-->
        <a class="getitemval" id="10" href="#"><img width="13" border="0" height="12" alt="" src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/plus.png"></a></div>
        </div>
                    <div class="itemscontainer">
        <div id="itemname_13" class="itemname">soup item 2</div>
        <div id="itemprice_13" class="itemprice">1400</div>
        <div class="itemaddsign">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="sessid" id="sessid" value=""  />-->
        <a class="getitemval" id="13" href="#"><img width="13" border="0" height="12" alt="" src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/plus.png"></a></div>
        </div>
                    <div class="itemscontainer">
        <div id="itemname_14" class="itemname">soup item 3</div>
        <div id="itemprice_14" class="itemprice">800</div>
        <div class="itemaddsign">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="sessid" id="sessid" value=""  />-->
        <a class="getitemval" id="14" href="#"><img width="13" border="0" height="12" alt="" src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/plus.png"></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
            <div class="Menudetailtitle">salad menu</div>

    <div class="Menudproducts">
                <div class="itemscontainer">
        <div id="itemname_11" class="itemname">salad item 1</div>
        <div id="itemprice_11" class="itemprice">1400</div>
        <div class="itemaddsign">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="sessid" id="sessid" value=""  />-->
        <a class="getitemval" id="11" href="#"><img width="13" border="0" height="12" alt="" src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/plus.png"></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
            <div class="Menudetailtitle">appetizer menu</div>

    <div class="Menudproducts">
                <div class="itemscontainer">
        <div id="itemname_12" class="itemname">appetizer item 1</div>
        <div id="itemprice_12" class="itemprice">1500</div>
        <div class="itemaddsign">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="sessid" id="sessid" value=""  />-->
        <a class="getitemval" id="12" href="#"><img width="13" border="0" height="12" alt="" src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/plus.png"></a></div>
        </div>
                    <div class="itemscontainer">
        <div id="itemname_15" class="itemname">appetizer item 2</div>
        <div id="itemprice_15" class="itemprice">3600</div>
        <div class="itemaddsign">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="sessid" id="sessid" value=""  />-->
        <a class="getitemval" id="15" href="#"><img width="13" border="0" height="12" alt="" src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/plus.png"></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I am using ajax and send item name, quantity, price and item id to my codeigniter controller and there i am also using codeigniter cart library to handle cart
Following is my ajax response when user add three item in cart

```
<p class="ctitle">soup item 1</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 1200/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="10">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="ctitle">soup item 2</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 1400/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="13">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="ctitle">soup item 3</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 800/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="14">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
```

and suppose user click on item 1 plus icon again then that item quantity will be 2 and its price is multiply by 2 and i get following ajax response:

```
<p class="ctitle">soup item 1</p>
<p class="cartqty">2</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 2400/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="10">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="ctitle">soup item 2</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 1400/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="13">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="ctitle">soup item 3</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 800/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="14">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
```

I send back complete cart in ajax response, suppose user click on first three items then ajax response will be

```
<p class="ctitle">soup item 1</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 1200/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="10">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="ctitle">soup item 2</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 1400/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="13">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
<p class="ctitle">soup item 3</p>
<p class="cartqty">1</p>
<p class="cartprice">Rs. 800/-</p>
<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;">
    <a href="#" id="14">
        <img src="http://localhost/food4u/front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg"
            width="12" height="12" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Now i have two issues:

1. ajax response show in firefox firebug but actually it is not added in page source code
2. there is order_cartdelete.jpg icon in ajax response which will delete or minus items from cart, delete when one item in cart and if two same item in cart then on one click it will minus one item from cart and retain remaining one item in cart

The following is my ajax code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    var link = "/food4u/";
    jQuery('.itemaddsign a').click(function() {
        var itemid = $(this).attr("id");
        var itemqty = 1;
        var itemdel = '';

        var itemname = jQuery('#itemname_'+itemid).text();
        var itemprice =  jQuery('#itemprice_'+itemid).text();
        $.post(link + "site/add_cart_item", { itemid: itemid, itemname: itemname, itemqty: itemqty,  itemprice: itemprice, ajax: '1', itemdel: itemdel },

        function(data){
            $('.ctitle11').remove();
            $('.carttitle11').empty(data);
            $('.carttitle11').append(data);         
        }); 

        return false;
    }); 
    });
```

If u want to see my controller then pleas have a look:

```
function add_cart_item()
{
    $itemid = $this->input->post('itemid');       // Assign posted item id to $itemid
    $itemname = $this->input->post('itemname');   // Assign posted item name to $itemname
    $itemqty = $this->input->post('itemqty');     // Assign posted item quantity to $itemqty
    $itemprice = $this->input->post('itemprice'); // Assign posted item price to $itemprice     

    $cart = $this->cart->contents(); 
    $exists = false;    
    $rowid = '';

    foreach($cart as $item)
    {       
        if($item['id'] == $itemid)     
        {
            $exists = true;
            $rowid = $item['rowid'];
            $qty = $item['qty'] + $itemqty;
            $price = $item['price'] * $qty;
            $name = $item['name'];                              
        }
    }       
    if($exists)
    {
        { 
        $cartlists = $this->cart_model->update_item($rowid, $name, $qty, $price);
        }
    }
    elseif($this->cart_model->validate_add_cart_item() == TRUE)
        {           
            $cartlists = $this->cart_model->validate_add_cart_item();
        }

        $cart2 = $this->cart->contents();
        foreach($cart2 as $cartsecond)
        {
            $rowid11 = $cartsecond['rowid'];
            $itemid11 = $cartsecond['id'];
            $itemqty11 = $cartsecond['qty'];
            $itemprice11 = $cartsecond['price'];
            $itemname11 = $cartsecond['name'];
            $itemsubtotal11 = $cartsecond['subtotal'];


        $cil = '';
        $cil .= '<p class="ctitle">'.$itemname11 . '</p>';
        $cil .= '<p class="cartqty">'.$itemqty11 . '</p>';
        $cil .= '<p class="cartprice">Rs. '.$itemsubtotal11 . '/-</p>';
        $cil .= '<p class="cdelete" style="margin:10px 0px 0px 7px; width:15px;"><a href="#" id="'.$itemid11.'"><img src="'. base_url() . 'front/images/order_cartdelete.jpg" width="12" height="12" border="0" /></a></p>'; 
        echo $cil;   
    }
}
```

ajax response is in `data` how can I extract information from it and perform reverse action on it and also how can I retain cart item in cart when user refresh page or browse any other page